# User Can Enter Data Despite Validation Excel

Tags: excel, validation, data-entry

I created data validation in Excel 2010 for certain cells that incorporates offset.

Here's an example of the validation used in one of the cells:

```
=OFFSET(Source_Sheet;5;MATCH(C6;GOALS;0)-1;4;1)
```

I want the user to choose only from the options offered by the data validation. However, it turns out that the user can actually type in manually anything they want and no error message appears despite the data validation!

How do I prevent the user from entering data other than the validated entries?

Comment: What does the validation range (the results of your `OFFSET` formula) present to the user? Is your validation a List, Custom, Whole Number, etc?

Comment: Make sure your offset is correct and it points and the cels you want to use for data validation.  I have never encountered any bugs related to data validation, so the odds are that you offset formula is not pointing at the cells that you actually want to be used.

Comment: @PeterT my validation is a list.

Comment: @MichalRosa it doesn show the user what I want them to see, actually. In fact, from the drop-down menu, the user can only choose from among the things I want them to choose. But they can circumvent this simply by typing whatever they want in the cells instead of using the drop-down menu!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Error Alert to true, from the data validation tool box.
PFB the screenshot:

[image]